# Fastest way to search values in a massive dataframe inside a loop (now too slow)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, performance

I've got a DataFrame **`_my_df`** with a shape **`(5187470, 109)`** and I need to iterate it row by row to perform some tasks. One of the thing that should be done en each iteration is to find a string value in one of its columns, get the corresponding rows and use them in the tasks. This is a bottleneck and makes the execution too slow.

I've tried the following approaches without success:

```
# Some previous manipulation for the approaches
_grp = _my_df.groupby(_my_df['target'])
_records = _my_df.to_records(index=False)
  
# First approach as pandas usual - Very slow  
df_final = _my_df[_my_df['target'] == 'value']

# Second approach by grouping - Very slow  
df_final = _grp.get_group('value')

# Third approach using numpy - A little faster  
df_final = _my_df.to_numpy()[_my_df['target'].to_numpy() == 'value']

# Fourth approach using recarray - A little faster 
df_final = pd.DataFrame.from_records(_records[np.where(_records['target'] == 'value')])
```

But none of them are fast enough...Do you know any other approach I could use here?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: `df_final = _my_df[_my_df['target'] == 'value']` is the best you can do in Pandas. I'd suggest looking into libraries like dask

Comment: Your dataframe should take several GiB of RAM possibly even dozens). Selecting a subset requires to fully copy of the dataframe in Pandas (this is not efficient but Pandas is clearly not meant to operate on such a big dataframe in the first place). Additionally, operating on strings is inefficient because of Python (but also because strings are inherently quite slow). Comparing 5000000 strings object and possibly allocating/deleting/reference-counting 5000000 new objects is not gonna be fast.

Comment: The first thing to do is to convert strings to categorial values or even integers if possible. The conversion is slow (because of string) but then it makes the filtering much faster. Processors likes integers, a bit numbers and clearly not strings (especially unicode-based ones like in Python). Sorting the dataframe once can help (slow preprocessing but done once). Finally, consider not creating a new dataframe if this is possible. Computing rows directly should be better if done correctly since operations generally do not require all columns.

Comment: Note that for huge dataframes like this, (in-memory) relational database may be faster regarding your actual operation. Engine for such DB are often designed so to avoid expensive indirect data storage (Pandas dataframes are very inefficient for large DF with a lot of columns), and care about the algorithmic complexity thanks to indexing and clever methods. Strings are also generally more efficiently computed. That being said, not all engines are optimized.

Comment: Two thoughts, 1) convert to dict and process the dict (much fast then pandas) or 2) what if you set the index with target and selected by index? (must say though I'm not sure either of these will be faster)